# Preimage of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I have read paper. I don't understand this part:

let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be non continuous function and $D$ be the set of all discontinuity points of $f$. So, for every $x \not\in D$, and every open neighbourhood $V_{f(x)}$ of $f(x)$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $f(y) \in V_{f(x)}$ whenever $y \in U_x$.

Let $B = \{U_x: x \not\in D \text{ and } y \in U_x \Rightarrow f(y) \in V_{f(x)}\}$. The author said that $B$ is open and $F_{\sigma}$. I can understand why $B$ is open but I cannot understand why $B$ is an $F_{\sigma}$.

I am appreciate any help

Comment: Is $B$ supposed to be the union of the $U_x$?

Comment: What is $F_{\sigma}$?

Comment: Assuming that $B$ is supposed to be the union of the $U_x$, so that we have a subset of $X$, it need not be an $F_{\sigma}$. Let $\omega_1$ the first uncountable ordinal, and $X = [0,\omega_1]$. Let $f = \chi_{\{\omega_1\}}$. Then $D = \{\omega_1\}$ and $B = [0,\omega_1)$ is not an $F_{\sigma}$.

Comment: @SantanaAfton An $F_{\sigma}$ set is a countable union of closed sets.

Comment: What you ask makes no sense. What you wrote states that B is a family of nbhds of x with some property, not a nbhd of x.

Comment: Prove instead the equivalent statement that the set of points at which f is continuous is a closed G_delta set.

Comment: Is the space metric or perhaps first countable?